# How do I remove every reference to a closed windows?

Tags: python, pyqt5, window

In the below example, I open new child windows from the main one. For each new window, I add a reference to it in a list to keep track on all new window (I have plenty of them in my whole software).
My issue is when I have opened several windows and I have closed some of them, the references to those closed windows still appear in the list:

```
1 window open
[<__main__.window object at 0x000002B91B7D1798>]
2 windows open
[<__main__.window object at 0x000002B91B7D1798>, <__main__.window object at 0x000002B91B7D19D8>]
3 windows open    
[<__main__.window object at 0x000002B91B7D1798>, <__main__.window object at 0x000002B91B7D19D8>, <__main__.window object at 0x000002B91B7D1C18>]
4 windows open
[<__main__.window object at 0x000002B91B7D1798>, <__main__.window object at 0x000002B91B7D19D8>, <__main__.window object at 0x000002B91B7D1C18>, <__main__.window object at 0x000002B91B7D1E58>]

hereI closed the first two windows, so 3 windows are opened, but I still have :
[<__main__.window object at 0x000002B91B7D1798>, <__main__.window object at 0x000002B91B7D19D8>, <__main__.window object at 0x000002B91B7D1C18>, <__main__.window object at 0x000002B91B7D1E58>, <__main__.window object at 0x000002B91B8640D8>]
```

How can I really close the child window and don't have their reference in my list? Otherwise, they are not closed obviously.

here's the MRE

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import sys



class window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None ):
        super(window, self).__init__()
        self.centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)
        self.HBOX = QVBoxLayout()
        self.PB = QPushButton('open new window')
        self.PB.clicked.connect(self.new_window)
        self.HBOX.addWidget(self.PB)
        self.centralWidget.setLayout(self.HBOX)

        self.windows_list = []

    def new_window(self):
        self.windows_list.append(window(self))
        self.windows_list[-1].show()
        print(self.windows_list)

 
if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = window()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep in mind that closing a window does *not* delete it (unless the `Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose` attribute is set, which is not by default).

A possible solution is to override the `closeEvent` and send a custom signal.

```
class Window(QMainWindow):
    closed = QtCore.pyqtSignal(object)
    # ...
    def new_window(self):
        new_window = Window(self)
        self.windows_list.append(new_window)
        new_window.show()
        new_window.closed.connect(self.window_list.remove)

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        self.closed.emit(self)
```

Another possibility is to always set the `Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose` attribute and connect to the [`destroyed`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#destroyed) signal, but in that case you **cannot** rely on the signal argument (it doesn't match the actual deleted window), and a lambda with the window instance must be used instead:

```
class Window(QMainWindow):
    # ...
    def new_window(self):
        new_window = Window(self)
        self.windows_list.append(new_window)
        new_window.setAttribute(Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose)
        new_window.show()
        new_window.destroyed.connect(lambda: self.windows_list.remove(new_window))
```

<sub>Note that I capitalized the class name, as classes should not use lower cased names.</sub>

Comment: Nice. It works. I'm not sure to understand what you mean by "closing a window does not delete it" though. Even if their are no reference to this window anymore, the object is not deleted? I mean if no reference to that window exist we cannot have access to it anymore, right?

Comment: @ymmx closing a widget is technically the same as hiding it: the widget is *not* deleted by default, is just hidden. The actual differences are that a close event can be ignored (preventing the user to close a window) and that when a top level widget (a window)  is closed, Qt checks if other window are still visible, and if not it automatically quits the application (if [`quitOnLastWindowClosed()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qguiapplication.html#quitOnLastWindowClosed-prop) is True, the default). Besides that, unless the `WA_DeleteOnClose` is set, closing a widget just hides it. ->

Comment: -> As long as the QApplication is active, it keeps a list of **all** widgets and top level widgets (windows) that still exist, even if they are hidden (including those that have been *closed*). In fact, even if you don't have a reference to the window anymore, you can still get it from the list returned by `QApplication.topLevelWidgets()` (or `QApplication.allWidgets()` if it's not a window). A widget is only actually destroyed when `deleteLater()` is called (which is what happens if the `WA_DeleteOnClose` is set).

Comment: Okay, I get it. Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: Sorry, I should better clarify. If absolutely *no* reference to the widget exists (including no existing Qt parent), the widget is actually destroyed: that's due to the object being garbage collected, which calls the `__del__` method of the widget, which in turn calls `deleteLater()` on the Qt side *if* the widget has no QObject (or QWidget) parent. That's why widgets without parents that are created in a function are instantly deleted as the function returns if no python reference is created.

Answer (score 1):

You could send a signal with the `closeEvent`:

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot, pyqtSignal
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QMainWindow, QApplication, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout, QWidget
)
from PyQt5.QtGui import QCloseEvent


class window(QMainWindow):
    closed = pyqtSignal(QMainWindow)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(window, self).__init__()
        self.centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)
        self.HBOX = QVBoxLayout()
        self.PB = QPushButton('open new window')
        self.PB.clicked.connect(self.new_window)
        self.HBOX.addWidget(self.PB)
        self.centralWidget.setLayout(self.HBOX)

        self.windows_list = []

    def new_window(self):
        new_window = window(self)
        new_window.closed.connect(self.remove_window_from_list)
        self.windows_list.append(new_window)
        self.windows_list[-1].show()
        print(self.windows_list)

    @pyqtSlot(QMainWindow)
    def remove_window_from_list(self, window: QMainWindow) -> None:
        self.windows_list.remove(window)
        print(self.windows_list)

    @pyqtSlot(QCloseEvent)
    def closeEvent(self, a0: QCloseEvent) -> None:
        self.closed.emit(self)
        super().closeEvent(a0)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = window()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: It also works. Even if I do not understand the ` -> None` in the code though.

Comment: It's [type hinting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) telling you what the method is expected to return. It has no effect on the runnin code.